# How to make more than one process work correctly outside of the EDT

Tags: codenameone

I have created a class that inherits a container and displays images in sequence within a Button component.

I show the container at the bottom of the form, but when I try to interact with another form element I have to wait for the container to finish executing the animation.
public class ImagenesButton extends Container {

```
   public ImagenesButton(Resources res) {
        this.res = res;
        this.setUIID("ContainerPromocion");
        muestraImagenes();
    }

    private void muestraImagenes() {
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        Button btPromo = new Button("Cargando .....", "ContainerPromocion"); btPromo.getStyle().setAlignment(Button.CENTER);
        this.addComponent(btPromo);
        btPromo.addActionListener((e) -> {
            Display.getInstance().execute("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLGwKBmqfzI&t=3s");
        });
        
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    btPromo.setIcon(res.getImage("p" + i + ".png").scaledWidth(this.getWidth()));
                   
                    Component btActual = this.getComponentAt(0);
                    int aleatorio = aleatorio(5);
                    if (aleatorio == 1) {
                        this.replaceAndWait(btActual, btPromo, CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, true, 5000));
                    }
                    if (aleatorio == 2) {
                        this.replaceAndWait(btActual, btPromo, CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, true, 5000));
                    }
                    if (aleatorio == 3) {
                        this.replaceAndWait(btActual, btPromo, CommonTransitions.createFade(7000));
                    }
                    if (aleatorio == 4) {
                        this.replaceAndWait(btActual, btPromo, CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, true, 5000));
                    }
                    if (aleatorio == 5) {
                        this.replaceAndWait(btActual, btPromo, CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, true, 5000));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private int aleatorio(int x) {
        int num = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        num = r.nextInt(x) + 1;
        return num;
    }
}
How do I make them run at the same time?
```

Answer (score 0):

These processes are all happening on the EDT not outside of it. All UI interaction has to happen on the EDT.

This is a bug:

```
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
    while (true) {
```

Call serially invokes the `Runnable` on the EDT so you're creating an infinite loop on the EDT and blocking all future work. How is this not crashing for you?

Well, you invoke `replaceAndWait` which does some magic behind the scenes and essentially nests an EDT within an EDT.

Don't loop infinitely or even slowly within the EDT. Everything you do within it must be performant or your UI will come to a halt. Try avoiding the `AndWait` versions of APIs, they are powerful but they should be used in very specific circumstances as they have some problematic edge cases.

If you need something to happen every 5 seconds use a `UITimer` or use a callback from the replace method to do the next replace.